# Can't set text for UITextView after 'Command+delete' action?

Tags: ios, xcode6, ios-simulator, ios8.3

After I use 'Command+delete' to delete texts from UITextView in iOS-Simulator,I can no longer set any text for UITextView.

```
textView.text = @"any text"; //no longer works
```

Because text will be deleted automatically by UITextView and if I type through keyboard, it's all OK again.

Here is the code, it's quite simple.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,strong) UITextView *textView;
@end

@implementation ViewController


-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];

    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [button setTitle:@"setText" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.center = self.view.center;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(setText) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)setText{
    self.textView.text = @"any text"; 
}
```

Comment: We're not magicians, please provide detail, context, and expected results :)

Comment: is the TextView set as a strong?

Comment: @Schemetrical The code is quite simple. I can't set text for UITextView after typing `Commond+delete` on my keyboard.

Comment: try [self.view insertSubview:button belowSubview:self.textView]. Give a shot, maybe the textview layer is on the back or you can bringView to front [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.textView];

Comment: @Bejibun it's just a demo. There is no other view on UITextView in my own project.